# Display elements inline irrespective of window size

Tags: html, css

I need to display one `image` and one `textarea` side by side. They should always stick side by side together and spread along the full width of the window even if the window is resized (kinda responsive) . Image should have a fixed size and textarea should occupy full length till right most. When window is re-sized, width of `textarea` should get re-sized to fit inline with the Image. Below is my code :

```
//html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img width="30" height="30" alt="you" class="pic" src="http://www.frontiersin.org/Design/Images/default_profile.jpg"/>
    <textarea class="txt"></textarea>
</div>

//css
.wrapper {
    width : 100%;
    display : inline;    
}    

.pic {
    float : left;   
}

.txt {
    width : 100%;
    float : left;  
    height: 30px
}
```

Here is a js fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/manishkumarshr/ACszc/4/)

[image]

Comment: Did you try reducing the `textarea` width?

Comment: yes I did, they do come inline but they do not stay inline when the window is resized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Block_formatting_context) by wrapping your textarea in an element like a span and using this CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width : 100%;
    display : inline;
    float: left;
}
.pic {
    float : left;
    width:30px;
}
.txt {
    width : 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 4px 0 6px
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ACszc/20/)**

Comment: This is a good solution and one I've used many times myself. Definitely better if the image width can change. I didn't post it in this case due to what happens with the `textarea:focus`, for example to exacerbate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ACszc/26/. Easiest way to deal with this is to add a bit of padding.

Answer (score 4):

If the size of the image will never change, this is as good a solution as any:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ACszc/22/

```css
.wrapper {
    padding-left: 36px;
    position: relative;
}
.pic {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.txt {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I like this one better because it doesn't add unneeded extra markup to get the job done.

Comment: There is problem with this, when resized, the textarea stays inline but it's width doest reduces to fit the window size. you can try that in a simple html file. :)

Comment: @ManishKumar: Sure it does. Here's a "simple HTML file": http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ACszc/22/show/. You must be doing something different on your page. Here's a version with `float: left; width: 100%` working on `.wrapper` as you have it in your question: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ACszc/28/. I initally removed those properties because I can't see what they're doing for you; they appear to be useless.

Comment: I see that, it does. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ACszc/25/) out.

Probably having width in percenteage ang height set to auto may help here.

```
.wrapper {
    width : 100%;
    display : block; 
    float: left
}


.pic {
    float : left; 
    width:3%;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 100%;
}

.txt {
    width : 95%;
    float : left;  
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: may be because of padding in certain element. Not sure though.. I guess the percentage calculations have to be pretty strict in this case

Answer (score 0):

Using tables can sometimes be very effective when dealing with INPUTs, even if quite ugly.
Also, it shouldn't mess with any browser :

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr>
    <td style="width:40px;">
        <img width="30" height="30" alt="you" class="pic" src="http://www.frontiersin.org/Design/Images/default_profile.jpg"/></td>
    <td style="width=100%;">
    <textarea class="txt"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When other solutions can't help you, think about it.